# How can I write all logs in a file locally in IOS other than crashes?

Tags: ios, debugging, logging

I want to write all logs in a file and need to export for troubleshooting and debugging in IOS?

Comment: There are many third party libraries available. You can use those.

Comment: you can use CocoaLumberjack : https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack

Comment: @Mahendra I need native solution.

Comment: You need native solution that is I think too broad to post here.

Comment: @Mahendra It is very simple thing. I got my answer and it's working. We can't let every topic go by saying it has too broad scope.

Comment: Sometimes the question asked seems too broad like this one. So that need some more clarification. By writing just one line in question and hoping that some will provide the complete solution doesn't happen every time. Anyway great to hear that you got your desired answer. cheers !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logging via OS_LOG and redirecting them to a file**

```
//objective c code
#import <os/log.h>

//insert below lines in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
//this will create a log file when your application is opened in documents directory with the file name of timestamp when app is opened
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log",[NSDate date]];
    NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr); //this will create/open a file in append mode and redirect the console logs to it


//below are example how to write logs with os_log 
    os_log_info(os_log_create("com.my.app", "application"), " custom info log"); // for log level : info , similarily there are functions like os_log_error, os_log_debug etc
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "default custom log");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some third party libraries and CocoaLumberjack one of them. To use CocoaLumberjack you can use cocoapods to install it.
In terminal write and enter  below command to install cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then from terminal got to your project directory where your “ProjectName.xcodeproj” is located.
Now create a pod file by using below command from terminal:

```
pod init
```

Then open the pod file using TextEdit  and add “pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'” before end .it will look like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target ’YOUR_TARGETNAME’ do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'

end
```

Now from terminal run the below command :

```
pod install
```

If CocoaLumberjack installed successfully then”Quit” your Xcode and open the file named “ProjectName.xcworkspace” instead of “ProjectName.xcodeproj”
Then  first build the project.

Then import CocoaLumberjack in your file (I did that in ViewController)

```
import CocoaLumberjack
```

Then inside viewDidLoad() I have added the logger:

```
DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance) // Uses os_log

let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
DDLog.add(fileLogger)
DDLogVerbose("log from viewDidLoad")
```

Details documentation of CocoaLumberjack is [here](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)

Comment: Thanks for comment. but I need native solution.